# Add "Chapter" or "Appendix" before numbers in Contents without the tocloft package

Tags: table-of-contents, titles

First a MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\begin{appendix}
\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to improve two points of the output:

1. **add "Chapter" or "Appendix" before numbers in Contents;**
2. **make the chapter and appendix titles without the words Chapter or Appendix or numbers be indent the same.**

The solution to the two problems which I could find the cite are almost appeals to the `tocloft` package which is undesired, for example

```
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{calc}%widthof
%add Chapter before numbers in Contents
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
%change Chapter to Appendix before numbers in Contents
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
%make chapter and appendix titles without the words Chapter or Appendix or numbers be indent larger
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix\space00\space}}}
```

So is there any solution invoking no `tocloft` or taking as less packages as possible to change the default command `\tableofconts` as less as possible?

Comment: Could you clarify why `tocloft` is unacceptable? It's such a strange request that it's hard to figure out which constraints you might be working under.

Comment: @Miyase The `tocloft` package will change some settings of the Contents in my file, for example line spread, and I don't know whether it will affect on some other settings.

Comment: `tocloft` only changes what you tell it to do. What do you mean by "line spread"? Perhaps you could add code to your question that shows your problem with `tocloft`. Or ask another question.

Comment: @PeterWilson I don't know why the line spreads are different whether to use `tocloft` in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch the command `\@chapter` and the command `\l@chapter`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\chapnwd}
\settowidth{\chapnwd}{\textbf{Appendix\space00\space}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}{\protect\numberline{\@chapapp\space\thechapter\space}#1}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{false}}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}}{\setlength\@tempdima{\chapnwd}}{\@latex@info{true}}{\@latex@info{false}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}


\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter*{test}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}


\begin{appendix}
\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me which file the `\@chapter` command lies in?

Comment: @M.Logic The`book.cls`

Comment: @M.Logic I add the method to make the indent same. Is this what you want?

Comment: Excellent work!

Answer (score 0):

You have still not clarified by what you mean by "line spread". You have not shown what your problem is with `tocloft` so all I can do is guess that this should work for you.

```
% tocloftprob.tex  SE 645714

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage%[titles] % this option does not reset the title spacing
    {tocloft}

  \addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}  % space for Chapter/Appendix number
  \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}

\begin{appendix}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix }}

\chapter{Basic Concepts}
\section{Theory}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```